# Trying to determine the best way to write a trigger on a file(ContentDocument) which is uploaded and Is realted via COntntDocumentLink to a Case

Tags: apex, trigger, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am very new to Apex (I wrote one two line trigger and test class successfully) and am trying to figure out this scenario.

When a customer or internal user uploads a file related to a Case I need an email to be sent to the customer who's case the file was uploaded to and to a second static email address.

My plan, I think, is to write an After.insert trigger on the ContentDocument that calls a helper class......but this may not be the right approach. Any thoughts comments, ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The helper class needs to then have several steps.

1) parse the linkedEntityID;s to see if the ContentDocument was linked to a case. If not nothing else needs to happen, If True proceed to step 2;

2) If the ContentDocuemnt was linked to a case I need to get the LinkedEntityID from the ContentDocumentLink which links the ContentDocument to the case.

3) Then I need to Retrieve the Contact ID from the case.

4) I then need to retrieve the Contact email from the Contact.

4) Send an email.(This part I think I can sort out as the are plenty of examples of how to do this.

Comment: Content Documents object is not supported in Workflow and process builder.

Comment: You will have to write a trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` and not `ContentDocument` as `LinkedEntityId` is a field on `ContentDocumentLink` which won't be created until that moment.